# Can I use the windows key again?

Tags: windows

My laptop, which was bought 4 years ago, has a windows 7 home premium key on its back. 2 years ago, I formatted my entire hard disk and installed windows 8. However, I want to go back to windows 7 now. Can I use the key again on the same laptop?

Comment: When I try to download windows from the OEM website, it says, "The Page or File You Requested Could Not Be Provided".
Link: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso

Comment: When you have formatted and install windws 8 i presume that you would have lost all windows 7 key intomation. Look for the microsoft sticker (if there is one) on the bottom of your laptop. May be the sticker has the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As long as you use the same product version. (E.g. Home Premium or Professional)

Architecture (x86 or x64) doesn't matter with regards to activation.

Also as this is usually a point of confusion, it does **NOT** matter if your media is OEM or Retail. (i.e using a generic, non OEM media **WILL** work)

As long as the product version is correct you shouldn't have any issues with activation.

Comment: It did not matter. I downloaded the same product with same architecture and the key worked perfectly. Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Provided you can find the installation media for your model computer.  The key will only work with the right software.  A generic Win 7 installer will not work.

Comment: I am downloading "windows 7 home premium". This is exactly written in the back of my laptop above the key. I dont care about the drivers becoz i can manage all those. Will the key work?

Comment: Yes the key will work

Comment: My download is the retail version becoz the OEM version link doesnot work. Link: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso